# Process data before express renders page

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Using node and express, I'm trying to process some information before the response renders the page, but I'm not having any luck doing so. Any suggestions?

```
app.get("/Category", function (request, response) {
    if (request.query.Id) {
        // get all the posts by categoryId

        ForumPost.find({categoryId: request.query.Id}, function (err, posts) {
            if (err) throw err;

            var usernames = {};

            for (i = 0; i < posts.length; i++) {
                User.findById(posts[i].userId, function (err, user) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    var username = user.username;
                    usernames[i] = username;
                });
            }
            response.render("Category", {
                message: posts,
                userList: usernames
            });

        });
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with react at all, this should just be standard Express.js

Comment: fair point, I could have sworn I clicked through a react post, and thus read it under that assumption. Forget I said something =P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want to query the DB only once, using a single `find` with all the user ids passed in as single `$in` filter, and then make sure you form your response in the callback handler that mongoose wants you to pass in as second argument to the `find` function:

```
// build the list of all ids you need
var ids = posts.map(p => mongoose.Types.ObjectId(p.userId));

// let's remove duplicates, too
ids = ids.filter((id,pos) => ids.indexOf(id)===pos);

// find all these users in a single query:
User.find({
  '_id': { $in: ids}
}, (err, users) => {
  // handle the query result

  if (err) {
    // do something error related here
    return ...
  }

  // no error: get the usernames and send the response
  var usernames = users.map(user => user.username);
  response.render("Category", {
    message: posts,
    userList: usernames
  });
});
```

This uses modern arrow functions, but if you're on an old version of Node (pre-6) those are easily replaced with classic function signatures (`(a,b,...) => c` is equivalent to `function(a,b,...) { return c }`. Technically they're `(function(a,b,...) { return c; }).bind(this)` but that's not a relevant distinction in the code above).

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution, it worked perfectly. I honestly had no idea about the $in filter available to me. Appreciate it.

Comment: Just realized I have another question actually, what if I wanted to allow duplicates? I got rid of the line with the comment that mentioned that, but it still wont give me duplicates. I want to map usernames[i] to posts[i] if that helps anything.

Comment: the database won't give you duplicates because "id in {1,1,1,1,1}" and "id in {1}" are the same result, the only reason we're filtering the `id` list is because a SQL round trip is really slow compared to working in memory, so by removing all the duplicates from `ids` we speed up the query. Rather than "wanting duplicates", think of what data you actually need - just having duplicates won't do you any good, so what is the thing you want to form *with* that information? Because you can typically ask the DB for that and it can get it for you as part of your query.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation, that makes a lot of sense. What I actually want to form with the information is to know which username is associated with which post, so I can display the username with the post in my view.

Comment: That's the kind of thing true SQL is pretty good at, but mongo is just a data store, so you may want to have a look at something like https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/, or otherwise you might need some more details in your queries that let you preserve which postid was associated with which userid so you can pull it back in as part of the find callback.

Answer (score 0):

You're actually triggering a lot of finds at the database. User.findById is an async method, and returns a query, which can be casted to a promise, and be fulfilled eventually. So those callbacks have not been executed necessarily by the time you hit

```
response.render("Category", {
    message: posts,
    userList: usernames
});
```

Once you render some response, your response headers are sent with or without the proper values on the username variable.
Take a look at [Promises/A+](https://promisesaplus.com/).

Comment: I've read over the documentation and am still a little confused about how exactly to implement a promise. I would put the response.render() call inside the then method? I'm having a difficult time grasping this.

Comment: The response above is actually a better approach, but in case you need something to be triggered and you don't rely on the response to further processing, then you might use promises to eventually make sure everything went well. This is also important to avoid i/o blocking.

Comment: Suppose you want to send a message to several users and wait for any one to response, you may implement this as an array of promises and continue when any one answers.

["The competitive race pattern may be used if one or more of the entire possible set of eventual outcomes are sufficient to resolve a promise."](https://github.com/cujojs/when/blob/master/docs/api.md#array-races)